# How to use size() function to get number of cars in a train agent

Tags: anylogic

I'm using the railyard library and after a train source block I have a select output that loops back to another flowchart block if the train is greater than 25 cars. For the code of this select output I've tried `agent.size() > 25;` `train.size() > 25;` and `int size() > 25` but everything comes up with errors. Am I using the wrong naming convention for my agent (and if so where do I find my agent name), or how do I tweak this code to use this function correctly?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `agent.size()>25` but without the semicolon

This is a condition, not a normal line of code.

Comment: When I use this code it says "size cannot be resolved or is not a field." How do I fix that?

Comment: You need to adjust the code to get the actual number of rail cars in your agent. Check how you do this insight of the train agent and use that